# AS3: Determining when a DisplayObject has been removed from the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, stage

The REMOVED_FROM_STAGE event is fired *before* the object is actually removed from the stage. I'm looking for a performant way to know when the object is finally removed. Suggestions?

Comment: One hackish way is to start a timer when REMOVED_FROM_STAGE occurs to set a slight delay to wait for it to be removed, but I recommend this only as a last resort.

Comment: I appreciate your not including that as an answer! ;)

Comment: lol, out of curiosity what exactly are you trying to accomplish once you know a display object is removed from the stage?

Comment: Since AS3 is an asynchronous language, you can never get an event that happens EXACTLY as something happens. It's either going to be before or after. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm less concerned with my specifics, and interested in approaches to the problem as there is no direct solution. Question edited to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the objects stage value.

```
if (!object.stage) {
  //not added to display list
}
```

Possibly set up an enterframe listener when `REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` is triggered.

```
object.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removed, false, 0, true);

private function removed(e:Event):void {
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removed);    
    e.target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkStage, false, 0, true);
}

private function checkStage(e:Event):void {
    if (!e.target.stage) {
        //object has been removed
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkStage);
        //do something now it has been removed
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like the use of ENTER_FRAME, but it certainly should work. +1

Answer (score 1):

How are you removing your object?

The last event before the screen is redrawn and you would see that your object has been removed is the render event.

Could you not listen out for that? As if an object is removed from the stage, the stage will have to redraw itself.

```
stage.invalidate();
stage.addEventListener(Event.RENDER, doAfter, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Great idea. I edited to add example code for others who might be curious. You need to call invalidate() on stage to catch the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if the target object's parent property is null.
When and how you check this depends on your application structure etc.

```
if (targetObject !== null && targetObject.parent === null) {
    // target object has been removed from display list
} else {
    // target object is still in display list
}
```